# I tried hashing the password but getting the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

Error: data and salt arguments required
at Object.hash (D:\social-media\rest-api\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:137:17)
at D:\social-media\rest-api\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
at new Promise ()
at Object.module.exports.promise (D:\social-media\rest-api\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
at Object.hash (D:\social-media\rest-api\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:133:25)
at D:\social-media\rest-api\routes\auth.js:8:45

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/Users");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        });
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});

router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.send("runing");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you try logging `req.body.password` , it might be undefined

Comment: this isnt working? what to do???

Comment: I tried your code it's working fine. Try logging ```req.body.password```, also make sure that you are using ```body-parser``` middleware.

Comment: can you share what changes you made? i am still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

How about only use `const` in `bcypt.hash`

`const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)`